# Reflexion in java

Tags: java

### Heading

Just a little question i can't figure

```
    Person per = new Person();
    Class cla = per.getClass();

    for(Method m : cla.getDeclaredMethods())
         System.out.println(m);
```

for example i have in my class Person method lined like this: setName,setSecondName,getName,getSecondName and when i list the Object m my output is getName and below setName so to the last method. Can someone explain me why the method is not lists as they lined up in my Class Person?Thanks

Here is my problem in full:

```
    Person per = new Person();
    Class cla = per.getClass();

    for(Method m : cla.getDeclaredMethods())
    {
         System.out.println(m.getName());
        if(m.getParameterCount() > 0){
             Parameter [] pa = m.getParameters();
             if(pa.length == 1){
                 if(m.getName().equals("setName") )
                     m.invoke(per , "John");
                 else if(m.getName().endsWith("setSecondName"))
                     m.invoke(per, "Cameron");
             }

        }
         else
             System.out.println(m.invoke(per));
    }
```

Acutal output:

getName

null

setName

setSecondName

getSecondName

Cameron

Comment: What makes you think that the output would be in the order that you used in the source file?

Comment: Do not use raw types.

Comment: Something like Name: Milos, Second name: Maksimovic. The actual problem it was a null (instance varible name in my class).  I solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Look at JavaDoc:

> **public Method[] getDeclaredMethods()
>                               throws SecurityException**
>
> Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the declared
>   methods of the class or interface represented by this Class object,
>   including public, protected, default (package) access, and private
>   methods, but excluding inherited methods.
>
> If this Class object represents a type that has multiple declared
>   methods with the same name and parameter types, but different return
>   types, then the returned array has a Method object for each such
>   method.
>
> If this Class object represents a type that has a class initialization
>   method , then the returned array does not have a corresponding
>   Method object.
>
> If this Class object represents a class or interface with no declared
>   methods, then the returned array has length 0.
>
> If this Class object represents an array type, a primitive type, or
>   void, then the returned array has length 0.
>
> **The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any
>    particular order.**

Answer (score 0):

The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order.

[JAVA API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods())